# rewrite $(\sqrt{5} + 2)(\sqrt{5}-2) = 1 $ until...

Tags: proof-writing

"rewrite $(\sqrt{5} + 2)(\sqrt{5}-2) = 1 $ until you have an equation with $\sqrt{5}$ on the left and a ratio of two expressions involving $\sqrt{5}$ on the right."

Ok..All i need to know is if i'm reading this question wrong. Are they asking me if they want an equation that looks like $\sqrt{5}$ = $\sqrt{5}$/ab   or something along the lines of that? because if so, i'm finding that to be an impossible task. I've multiplied the equation so many times by 1s and added 0's but i'm always finding myself ending with $\sqrt{5} = \sqrt{5} $

**I'm aware that there is a question out there with the same equation this is not a duplicate.**

Comment: If I understand it correctly, they expect it to be written as $\sqrt5 = \dfrac{a\sqrt 5 + b}{c\sqrt 5 + d}$

Comment: @taninamdar had to make a quick edit sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would divide by $\sqrt5 - 2$ and then subtract 2. Or divide by $\sqrt5+2$ and then add 2.

Comment: seems too easy...:x

Comment: If it works, it's right, isn't it? Try it and see!